# Tkinter/Webbrowser : tab opening dimension/position control ? open resize and display in a grid, youtube video in a Gui

Tags: python

I'm new in python and the programming in general.

I would like to create an application that opens 8  web pages -lives pages from youtube - . Opening and controling the dimensions of each page to form a grid all over my screen ?

I found a library to open a web browser, but having trouble getting the grid layout and positioning correct.

Here is the code:

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab ("https://www.Owertube.bl")
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Ps: Idealy I would like to stream youtube videos in a Gui... Like I open an .exe and it opens the Gui and start the stream (sound off would be the must) ... Seems complicated, i'v seen how to show a video with tkinter like your webcam but not youtube links.

Something like the YouTube Live Streaming API by google, but home made, is it that complicated ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you've used to try and get "the grid layout and positioning correct" so we might be able to point out where specifically your attempt has gone wrong?

Comment: well for the moment i don't have any grid... thats the point how to open them in a grided tab ?

Comment: Have you considered  using another approach i.e. open one webbrowser page that has 9 iframes embedding the steaming views you want to see? I think it might be easier to implement as you only need to position one browser, as well as you can adjust how many iframes you want i.e 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc.

Comment: oh thanks ! yes i can try this !!

Comment: @noobie // seems a bit complicated to make the webbrowser open differents iframes (probably i didn't spend enough time on it). but if you have an idea about how to wright it, will be lovely

Comment: @qsdwv It should be easy to set it up. check this out to help you get going https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm. I do not know your use case, so even though I suggested this approach, it might not be a suitable solution to the problem you are trying to solve.